# Route [signup] not defined in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel. I am learning how to create user registration page. Everything works fine but I am stuck in a simple problem.

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
>   Route [signup] not defined. (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\social\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

But I defined signup route. Here is my **routes.php** file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as' => 'signup'
]);
```

And this is my **UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['frist_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);


        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->frist_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
```

Blade file is **welcome.blade.php**

```
 <form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email"> Your E-mail </label>
           <input class ="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" >
         </div>
```

I would be much obliged if anyone could help me. 
Thanks

Oh, Sorry. I forget to mention that I am using ***Laravel version: 5.4.11***

Comment: Try running `composer install` and `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: Route::post('/signup', ['as' => 'signup','uses'=>'UserController@postSignUp']); and the form action is  <form action="{{ url('/register') }}"  method="post"> use this it will work...

Comment: Thank you @StuartWagner 

I did all but it does not work  :(

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` and make sure your 'signup' route shows up.

Comment: @Sona 
Yes, It shows the welcome page but when I am submitting data through form it says  `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: what it sayss...?? <form action="{{ url('/signup') }}" method="post"> add this

Comment: 'signup' route is not showing on the list  :( @StuartWagner

Comment: You're using Laravel 5.4, right? That version uses `routes/web.php` as the routes file.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan route:scan`

Comment: `Command "route:scan" is not defined. `@HimanshuSharma

Comment: Thanks a lot @StuartWagner  Its working. Solved! Actually I am following Laravel 5.2 tutorial  :(

Comment: @StuartWagner, named routes in Larevel 5.4 have different syntax comparing to 5.2 version of Laravel. This is likely the problem.

Comment: @prosti That is incorrect. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311369/route-signup-not-defined-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment72019078_42434311) to your answer below.

Comment: @StuartWagner, yes, you are correct, I removed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the completeness, as @StuartWagner replied since of Laravel 5.4 all routes are inside the `/routes` folder and not any more inside the `HTTP` folder.

The web routes are inside the `/routes/web.php` file.

This was often requested since otherwise, you would need to browse three levels deep to get the routes.

Now much better, they are in the `/routes` folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can change `{{route('/signup')}}`  to  `{{URL('/signup')}}`

```html
<form action="{{ URL('signup') }}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email"> Your E-mail </label>
   <input class ="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" >
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks saved me there

Answer (score 2):

laravel provide inbuilt auth functionality, you type following command in your terminal after select project:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

and you can use login,register and changes password functionality.
also refer **laravel authentication**

i hope, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form action="/signup" method="POST">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email"> Your E-mail </label>
           <input class ="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" >
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old but want to contribute  :)

```
Route::post('/signup', [uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp','as' => 'signup']);
```

add a name for route

```
Route::post('/signup', [uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp','as' => 'signup'])->name(signup);
```

When you are using the route inside your blade template then you have to give the name to your route to identify

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email"> Your E-mail </label>
           <input class ="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" >
         </div>
```